# How can I decrease and increase a text value on button-click by multiplying two numeric values?

Tags: ios

I have two values on different variables and want to add the multiplication of these values on uitextfield.

**For example**: the first value is 10 (the default value), and the second value is 30; the second value can be changed because it will always come from API. Now first I add the multiplication of these values on uitextfield.

If I click on the *increase* button, then the current value of text-field should be added to the second value (30) and be displayed, and so on.

The second thing is that when I click on the *decrease* button, it should be decreased by the second value (30), and so on.

It's a concept like a shopping cart.

Here is my code, which is not working properly:

```
 - (IBAction)IncreasePack:(id)sender {


[self.TotalPrice setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
NSLog(@"number %d", number);

number = number+firstincrease;
 NSLog(@"number %d", number);
 packnumber++;
_Packs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",packnumber ];
NSLog(@"packnumber %d", packnumber);



     }

  - (IBAction)DecreasePack:(id)sender {

 packnumber--;
_Packs.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", packnumber];

number = number-firstdecrease;
NSLog(@"number %d", number);
[self.TotalPrice setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];


    }
```

Comment: should i use nsuserdefault for this task here??

Comment: whats the error you face in your code ??? do you illustrate it properly?

Comment: so what is your problem ?. NSLog is giving you proper values?.

Comment: yes sir, its working properly when i press increase button but when i press decrease value of textfield decrease on second click this is the first issue, and second when i again press increase button it should be increase from he current value of textfield but it increase by the previous one.

Comment: yes sir, error is not there in my code  i just place wrong logic here, i need some suggestion on my logic

Comment: give some suggestions please. i am stuck here from few hours

Comment: what the problem u faced bro..

Comment: thanks for your response sir, my code working fine for first time increase and decrease button but if i press again increase button then it takes the previous value but it should be increase by the current textfield value with second(like in question 30).

Comment: in my question the value on "number is 310" which is coming dynamic and 310 is multiplication of default value(10) and dynamic value(30 it can be cahnge).

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik hello sir i think your answer is removed . i don't know why

Comment: I think it is wrong thats the reason bro

Comment: Ohh ok sir that's fine

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Hello sir should i wait for somme suggestion from your side.??

Comment: ok sir thanks you i need to do something at my end now than came back to you. i just spend much time n this logic

Comment: i think i am unable to describe my question correctly ha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104241/discussion-between-anbu-karthik-and-sandeep-tomar).